# How can I render 2D ropes in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, rope-physics

I'd like to be able to render flexible lines, or ropes, as below:

[image]

I thought about using a Line Renderer but it doesn't have the flexibility to render arbitrary curves.

Answer (score 6):

This effect can be easily accomplished with just hinge joints.

[image]

This above gif, was created without any code whatsoever.  Each link in the chain is connected to the one above it via a Hinge Joint 2D.  You can play around with the mass of the rope vs the object it is holding for better physic response

Point is, you shouldn't be using a line renderer for something like this.

Answer (score -3):

Its by using SetPosition Property.
Have a look at this.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPosition.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't fully read the question? This is a very incomplete answer.